# csvde doesn't import users

Tags: windows, directory

I have a small problem as I'm a server manager beginner, I installed a Domain Controller on my Windows Server 2008, and I created three OUs, now I'm trying to add users to each OU via `csvde` command, but I get as a result of the operation, without mentioning any errors:

```
> C:\csvde>csvde -i -f List.csv 
> Connecting to "(null)"
> Logging in as current user using SSPI Importing directory from file
> "List.csv" Loading entries. 
> 0 entries modified successfully.
```

Below is the csv file I'm using to add 2 users to "Offshoring1" OU, the domain name is "iado.lan".

> DN objectClass sAMAccountName sn givenName userPrincipalNAme
>   cn=BB NN,ou=Offshoring1,dc=iado,dc=lan user BB NN BB BB.NN@iado.lan
>   cn=II YY,ou=Offshoring1,dc=iado,dc=lan user II YY II II.YY@iado.lan

and this the csv data as generated by Word 2011 on my mac :

> DN;objectClass;sAMAccountName;sn;givenName;userPrincipalNAme
>   cn=BB NN,ou=Offshoring1,dc=iado,dc=lan;user;BB;NN;BB;BB.NN@iado.lan
>   cn=II YY,ou=Offshoring1,dc=iado,dc=lan;user;II;YY;II;II.YY@iado.lan

I do use `-k` option to force import but still no success.

Comment: Add `-v` for verbose output, also `-j` can be to generate logs.

Comment: Word for Mac is probably mangling your data. Use a plain-text editor instead, like `vi` or `textedit` in plain-text mode if you need a GUI.

Comment: @jscott : I've updated the output result displayed on my screen .

Comment: ` Connecting to "(null)"` -- You're not connecting to anything. You need to connect to a Domain Controller.  You can specify the DC with `-s NameOfDC`

Comment: @jscott : Even if i'm running the command on the server which is a DC  ??

Comment: @TheEighthEro Just tested running on a DC, you're correct, it returns `(null)` instead of the DC name. Odd.